# Connect Oracle wth PHP using SSH Connection

Tags: php, database, oracle, ssh, oracle12c

I have a client requirement to secure our application connection with the Oracle Database. Currently, we are using OCI8 PHP library (oci_connect) to connect to Oracle using credentials which we have in a config file (a kind of plain text) where we maintain all our credentials.

Now they want to improve the security by implementing some kind secure connection using SSH so communication from application to DB will be secure. I read on the internet that this is possible.

My problem is that I don't know to achieve that with PHP OCI library even if our administrator implement SSH based authentication between the application server and DB server because OCI library uses username and password to connect with DB server.

I am trying to understand if there is any way we can achieve this type of auth connections from PHP to Oracle.

I am using Oracle 12c Enterprise edition.

Comment: Looks like someone voted to Close this question. Any issues in the question?

Comment: Encryption is configured in the Oracle Network layer. The simplest to configure is Oracle's native encryption.  I know there is an example at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#securenetwork (All the OCI based DB drivers allow the same configuration : python, php, node.js etc).  SSL is more involved: check the Oracle manuals for your version of Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part - Establishing a secure connection using SSH. We can try using Oracle Wallets. So we don't need to save any plain text password in the app server.

Try connecting from PHP to an Oracle DB using an Oracle Wallet using below steps

1 - Create a wallet (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm#g1033548)

2 - Put the Oracle instant client and the wallet files somewhere on the server with PHP (for example /opt/instantclient and /opt/wallet)

3 - Start Apache with the following variables:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/instantclient   
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/instantclient   
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/wallet
```

4 - In /opt/wallet create a tnsnames.ora files with this content:

```
WALLET_NAME =  
  (DESCRIPTION =  
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DB_IP)(PORT = DB_PORT))    
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DB_SID))    
  )
```

where WALLET_NAME it's the name of the wallet chosen when the wallet has been created, DB_IP it's the database ip address or hostname, DB_PORT it's the db port, and DB_SID it's the sid of the database

5 - In /opt/wallet create a sqlnet.ora files with this content:

```
WALLET_LOCATION =    
   (SOURCE =     
     (METHOD = FILE)     
     (METHOD_DATA =     
       (DIRECTORY = /opt/wallet)     
     )      
    )     

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

6 -  Restart Apache

On the PHP code side now you can connect to the database opening a connection with the following code:

```
$conn = oci_connect("/", "", "WALLET_NAME", null, OCI_CRED_EXT);
```

OCI_CRED_EXT This *tells Oracle to use External or OS authentication, which must be configured in the database*. The OCI_CRED_EXT flag can only be used with username of "/" and a empty password.

Comment: Nice info but unrelated to the question of network encryption.

Comment: I was explaining how we can use SSH so communication from application to DB in a secure way using oracle wallets. So no need to save plain text passwords in server.    I updated my initial paragraph of my answer to clarify that. How this will .help